# SQL Server SELECT @VARIABLE = TOP 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to perform the following in a stored procedure

```
DECLARE @TICKET_AGE INT
SELECT @TICKET_AGE = TOP 1 (DATEDIFF(second, DATE_ENTERED, GETDATE())/60) AS TICKET_AGE
FROM TICKETS
```

But it's giving error saying INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR 'TOP'
What am i doing wrong?

So i've updated my code to look like below...but now am getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

```
    -- DECLARE VARIABLE
    DECLARE @TICKET_AGE INT

    -- PULL THE DATA
    SELECT TOP 1 @TICKET_AGE = (DATEDIFF(second, DATE_ENTERED, GETDATE())/60) AS TICKET_AGE
    FROM TICKETS
    WHERE LOWER(STATUS_DESCRIPTION) LIKE '%new%'
    ORDER BY DATE_ENTERED ASC
```

Comment: TOP 1 must be the first thing after SELECT, like this: SELET TOP 1 @TICKET_AGE = ...

Comment: You're assigning it to a variable.  You can't alias that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `TOP 1` comes *before* the variable:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @TICKET_AGE = DATEDIFF(second, DATE_ENTERED, GETDATE()) / 60
FROM TICKETS
```

Comment: Remember it's important to say *what* you changed.

Comment: @juergen d Thank you that fixed that error but now I get invalid syntax near the keyword 'As'.  Any ideas?  I updated my code in post to show full version now

Comment: Remove the  `AS TICKET_AGE` as in my answer

Comment: @juergend working perfectly!  Thanks!!! Will accept as correct as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it matters, but this should give you the same result and *might* perform better

```
SELECT  @TICKET_AGE = MAX(DATEDIFF(second,DATE_ENTERED,GETDATE()) / 60)
FROM    TICKETS
WHERE   LOWER(STATUS_DESCRIPTION) LIKE '%new%'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use your actual variable for the [`TOP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) statement (i.e. retrieve the top `@TICKET_AGE` rows), then you would could use :

```
SELECT TOP @TICKET_AGE DATEDIFF(second, DATE_ENTERED, GETDATE()) / 60
  FROM TICKETS
```